# How to implement a chat like facebook where User A sends message to User B without page refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want a communication between two people like facebook, User A messages to User B without refresh. And the message should be displayed between two people. But in my code message gets displayed after refresh only. Please help any one.

**chat window**

```
<div class="row msg_container base_sent">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <?php if (empty($roww->customer_image[0]) || empty($roww->supplier_image)) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/default.jpg" class="img-circle" width="30px" height="30px"/>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $roww->supplier_image; ?>" class="img-circle" width="30px" height="30px"/>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
        <div class="messages msg_sent">

            <p>
                <!--In this p tag i want to set a set timeout function how to call in ajax success without page reload-->
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="12am"><?php echo $row->message; ?> </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

                    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/buyer_communication',
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            scrollDown();
                            var message = $("#messagee").val();


                            $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');

                            $('#messagee').val('');


                        },
                        error: function ()
                        {
                            alert('failed');
                        }
                    });

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                scrollDown();
                function scrollDown() {
                    $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 200);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Good luck with that. Feel free to come back when you have a question?

Comment: @adeneo...what you saying

Comment: I'm saying you should ask a question, preferably with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @adeneo,my question is without refresh page message should be display communication between two people,in my code after refresh the page message displaying..are you got my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of option to achieve this but you can try an easier one.

Use `timed synchronous refresh` on your messages div.

It'll load the new messages without refreshing whole page but particular div automatically.

You just need to create a page which contains inner content of that div (messages container) then load that container timely.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var refresh = function () {
     $(".msg_container").load("messages.php");  // link of page to return list of messages
   }

setInterval(refresh, 9000);
  refresh();
});
```

You can also do a bit efficiently by fetching unread messages as json and appending content at end of messages list.